# Adding Properties to GeoJSON File

Tags: geojson, d3

I have a GeoJSON file of the country of Haiti with the administrative boundaries for communes (i.e. counties). Here is the file:

https://rawgit.com/mattbowlby/bf5243ab097e50eb8864/raw/46818c96bc49629681238d5302d597456227c040/haiti_communes.geo.json

That file has a few properties, for example:

```
( "properties": {
        "id_com": 112,
        "commune": "Delmas",
        "id_dept": 1,
        "dept": "West Department",
        "shape_leng": 0.242799419022,
        "latitude": 18.5543057016,
        "longitude": -72.297644435,
        "shape_le_1": 0.242799419022,
        "shape_area": 0.00222841371629
```

Now, I want to be able to add a number of new properties, such as area, population and other things. I have 141 different communes and do not want to enter this information manually. Is there a way to work with a GeoJSON file and add the properties, such as with a spreadsheet or other format? Ideally I would have it in a spreadsheet and add in the new properties as columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would download and install QGIS, and then open the geojson file by clicking **Add vector layer** button:

[image]

After that you should be able to see you geojson file in QGIS:

[image]

And right click the layer's name in the left hand layer list, and click "**Properties**"; then go to the "**Joins**" tab, and click the green plus icon on the left bottom corner to open "Add vector join":

[image]

Join the table with the fields you would like to append to your geojson file; then right click layer's name in the left hand layer list, and click "**Save As...**" to save the geojson file into a new file and you should have what you need. And make sure you specify the output format as "GeoJSON":

[image]

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I succeeded in installing QGIS and loading the GeoJSON file as in your example. However, when I go to Properties -> Joins for that layer and select "Add vector join", there are no join layers or join fields for me to select.

How do I get my new data in and added as properties to the file? For example, I have a spreadsheet listing population, area and other values to be added to each commune.

Comment: You need to add the spreadsheet to QGIS first as well. So I would save the spreadsheet as a CSV file, and then use "Add vector layer" to add the CSV file to the layer list, then you should be able to see the table when you open "Add vector join". If you can't get that work, maybe you can share the spreadsheet somewhere (like google doc) and I can edit my answer by adding some more screenshots.

Comment: Yes - that worked perfectly. It added the properties just as I wanted. Thank you for you help. I truly appreciate it. A very detailed answer with nice screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) Just upload your geojson file and add a column, and do your edits.

[image]

Once you are satisfied with your edits, you can just download the resulting geojson file

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: @mattbowlby You're welcome! Well enough for an upvote? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In case you work with d3 (as your tag suggests) here is an alternative using [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson).

For a tsv file "attributes.tsv" in the following format:

```
id  attribute
112 A
114 B
123 C
211 D
442 E
343 F
...
```

Convert to topojson:

```
topojson -o topojson.json haiti_communes.geo.json -p
```

Join:

```
topojson -o final.json -e attributes.tsv --id-property=+id_com,+id -p -- topojson.json
```

[hat tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444261/how-to-add-properties-to-topojson-file)

Comment: I will try this today and see if I can get it to work.